# How to access canvas element in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, canvas

Getting error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of undefined

```
var $ = jQuery = require('jquery'),
    Handlebars = require('handlebars'),
    Backbone = require('backbone'),
    _ = require('underscore'),
    piechartTemplate = require('../../templates/dashboard/piechart.html'),
   services = require('../../libs/services'),
   Chart = require('chart.js/Chart');

var PieChartView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#id-canvas",
    initialize: function() {
        this.$el.html(piechartTemplate);
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        var self = this;
        // this.ctx = this.$el.get(0).getContext("2d");
        var canvas = this.$el.get(0);
        console.log(canvas);
        this.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        console.log(this.ctx);

        this.chart = new Chart(self.ctx);
        var data = this.chartData();
        self.chart.Doughnut(data, {
            animateScale: true
        });
    },
    chartData: function() {
        var data = [{
            value: 300,
            color: "#F7464A",
            highlight: "#FF5A5E",
            label: "Red"
        }, {
            value: 50,
            color: "#46BFBD",
            highlight: "#5AD3D1",
            label: "Green"
        }, {
            value: 100,
            color: "#FDB45C",
            highlight: "#FFC870",
            label: "Yellow"
        }]
        return data;
    }
});

module.exports = PieChartView;
```

HTML:

```
<canvas id="id-canvas" height="500" width="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: When you say "HTML", you mean "../../templates/dashboard/piechart.html"?

Comment: Maybe change this.$el.get(0); to "this.$el.find("canvas#id-canvas")"?

Comment: What are you putting inside the canvas element with html(piechartTemplate)? Nothing is supposed to go in there except fallback content if canvas isn't supported. Does your console.log(canvas) have the correct element?

Comment: no canvas comes as undefined. i am trying to insert the Chart from chart.js

Comment: I can only imagine that it cannot find `'#id-canvas'` then. But a `debugger;` statement in Backbone's `_setElement` function and make sure it is finding the element

Comment: Can you set up a js fiddle?

Comment: Solved it used a document.getElementById it worked

Answer (score 0):

You need move main JS file from `<head>` tag just before the `<body>` tag or use jQuery DOM ready wrapper (but I personally prefer put script before `body`)

```
$(function() {
   ...
});
```